# How to subtract Time from current Time momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, momentjs

I have

```
const endTime = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
const duration = moment.utc(request.input('duration') * 60000).format("HH:mm:ss");
```

I want to calculate

```
startTime = endTime - duration
```

Comment: what is `request.input('duration')` ?

Comment: Duration in milliseconds.

Comment: I mean what is the value of `request.input('duration')`?

Comment: for example request.input('duration') = 40 minute

Comment: moment.utc(request.input('duration') * 60000).format("HH:mm:ss") = '00:40:00" when request.input('duration') == 40 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
endTime.subtract(duration);
```

Should do the trick ,here is the docs if you want to dig deeper [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Edit:

```
const endTime = moment(); //now time
const duration = request.input('duration') //duration in miliseconds
let startTime = endTime.subtract(duration,'ms')
```

```js
const endTime = moment(); //now time
const duration = 600000; //hardcoded 10 mins //duration in miliseconds
console.log(endTime)
let startTime = endTime.subtract(duration, 'ms')
console.log(startTime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you tell me more detail?

Comment: Running it with `Run code snippet` .. both logs return the same hour for me.

Comment: Fixed the example. Moment is not returning a new object

Answer (score 1):

You can use endTime.subtract(duration, 'ms'). But for that endTime has to be a moment object. So format the answer later.

```
const endTime = moment();
const duration = request.input('duration')
let startTime = endTime.subtract(duration,'ms').format('HH:mm:ss')
```